# PHP & Jquery Refresh id with external file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, refresh

I'm trying to refresh one ID of my page within the click of a button.
I've tried several ways but none of them work. Although I've created the button to refresh it, it keep the submission of the page (triggering the validation event). So, each time I click that button, he tries to submit the form, validation the inputs instead refresh that div.

Here's my code right now:

```js
function refreshCaptcha() {
 $("#captcha_code").attr('src','./inc/captcha.php');
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" id="refreshcap" name="refreshcap" onclick="refreshCaptcha();">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh push-5-r"></i>
        <img id="captcha_code" src="inc/captcha.php" />
    </button> 
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
 <div class="form-material floating">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cap" name="cap">
  <label for="cap">Captcha</label>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me trying to get what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your button is inside the form,

add `type` in your button

which will stop button from submitting your form

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" id="refreshcap" name="refreshcap" onclick="refreshCaptcha();">
            <i class="fa fa-refresh push-5-r"></i>
            <img id="captcha_code" src="inc/captcha.php" />
    </button>
```

other than that you can use `javascript` `return false;` in your function end

### with js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#refreshcap").on("click",function(event){
             event.preventDefault();
             $("#captcha_code").attr('src','./inc/captcha.php');
        });
    });
</script>
```

with this you wont need to call on click event this will do it for you, no matter type is `button` or `submit`

Comment: I've put the type on the button and now it doesn't try to submit the page, but it doesn't refresh that ID either. If I refresh manually the page it's working, but not with the JS code. It happens the same with return false in the function.

Comment: try putting an alert inside your function. which will tell you if your function is called or not.

Comment: see i have added a small js code in the answer, check it would be helpful and a solution to your problem

Comment: I've found the problem. Just forgot to start the session in PHP code, so it's being called but not worked because a new session isn't started. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your JS function should return false; in order to not submit the form.

```
<script>
function refreshCaptcha() {
    $("#captcha_code").attr('src','./inc/captcha.php');
    return false;
}
</script>
```